# error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant when using constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I tried to write three types of meta-programming template to check a class object is able to convert to an int or not.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct meta1
{
    static char(&resolve(int))[2];
    static char resolve(...);
    enum { value = sizeof(resolve(T())) - 1 };
};

template<typename T>
struct meta2
{
    struct result_yes { char _[2]; };
    typedef char result_no;
    static result_yes resolve(int);
    static result_no resolve(...);
    enum { value = sizeof(resolve(T())) - 1 };
};

template<typename T>
struct meta3
{
    static constexpr bool resolve(int) { return true; }
    static constexpr bool resolve(...) { return false; }
    enum { value = resolve(T()) }; // error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
};

#define CHECK(FUNC_NAME) \
cout << "Checking " #FUNC_NAME << endl; \
cout << FUNC_NAME<int>::value << endl; \
cout << FUNC_NAME<string>::value << endl; \

int main()
{
    CHECK(meta1)
    CHECK(meta2)
    CHECK(meta3)
}
```

and an error occured when using constexpr,
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
How can I fix this, and why this happened?

Thank you.

Comment: "call" inside `sizeof` is in unevaluated context (that's why you might omit definition). `enum { value = resolve(T()) };` is in evaluated context, and `string{}` is unusable in constant expression until C++20 (and currently not yet supported).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constexpr` marked functions don't actually need to be called at compile time. They can be, but they can also work at runtime, if their arguments are runtime things. In your case, an `std::string` would not work for `result` at compile time (since `std::string` can't be evaluated at compile-time - no constexpr constructor).

`int` can so for that it works.

the other methods work just fine since they don't use `constexpr` functions

EDIT: you could, maybe, benefit from `std::declval` instead of using `T()` [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

EDIT2: would this not be [an option](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) or is this for learning purposes?

Comment: Yes, this is for learning purposes. And it is a nice option using std::is_convertible. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: @colinzcli maybe take a look at: [link](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/a21dc9d1529b8a8071e36b22b6e8492fc2ce7d5a/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/type_traits#L1405)

Comment: I try to replace T() to declval<T>(), but same error(C2131) occured. This time even only passing int type to check convertable. Did I use it in a wrong way?

Comment: @colinzcli sorry, my bad, I think you're always evaluating with `result`, you can only use `std::declval` in unevaluated contexts... like `sizeof` or `decltype`

so it's useless here, at least it seems so

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this isn't working like it does in the other cases but as a work around you can turn `meta3` into

```
template<typename T>
struct meta3
{
    enum { value = std::is_same_v<T, int> };
};
```

Which will compile using C++17 or higher.  You can use `std::is_same<T, int>::value` if you want to suport C++11 or C++14.

Comment: I think it doesn't work because `constexpr` functions can also be called at runtime with runtime evaluated arguments